# Trivial search/replacement in Perl without error?

Tags: perl, search, replace

How to simply do a search/replace in Perl? The following example doesn't work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $text    = '***/**/*abc*/***//*';
my $search  = '/*abc*/';
my $replace = '#def#';

print "$text\n";
$text =~ s/$search/$replace/g;
print "$text\n";
```

Comment: Please include `use strict;` and `use warnings;` in EVERY perl script.  Even short ones.  *(added for you)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that content of `$search` has quoted meta-chars by using `\Q` or [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) in order to be treated as literal string,

```
$text =~ s/\Q$search/$replace/g;
```

Answer (score 4):

`$search` is not treated as a string, but as a regular expression. The character `*` has a special meaning in regular expressions so you need to quote it. Try:

```
$search = quotemeta '/*abc*/';
```

Comment: or you do the quoting while interpolating in the regex: `s/\Q$search\E/$replace/g`